# How to save the state of button without using onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-button, android-orientation

I have a layout where I have a button. This button has 2 properties I'm interested in: text and color.

Now I know that if we mention `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest for this activity, we are telling that "we will handle it manually."

Now I don't want to add this in the manifest and let Android handle it automatically.

PROBLEM: Here when the user clicks on the button, I am changing the color as well as the text. Now when the screen orientation changes, the button color changes. How should I handle this?

For some reason and requirements, I don't want to use `onSaveInstanceState`. I have the same problem with a seek bar, also.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "For some reason and requirements i dont want to use this onSaveInstanceState" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare ok i have a graph which will change it position from center to left,bottom etc... so

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with avoiding `onSaveInstanceState()`. The right answer is for you to store your own information regarding this button in the `Bundle` supplied to `onSaveInstanceState()`, then use that information in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: yes thats why i have mentioned "Is there any way to do this?" anyways so we cannnot avoid onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: CommonsWare comment is the right way to do it, but if you have a personal vendetta with the `onSaveInstanceState` method you could always use a persistent storage(preferences, files, database etc) to store the values in `onPause` and restore them in `onResume`.

Comment: you can use putextera for your current intent in onPause and getextera in onResume too